# How to learn qt, entirely in C++ - without touching qt designer?

Tags: c++, qt

So i am basically a newbie when it comes to qt. I want to learn it ,but entirely in C++ and without even touching desinger because for me it's not coding anymore. The problem is that every single tutorial/guide/book uses it and the API documentation is just (for me) overwhelming - i dont know where to start.

Comment: These kind of questions are _off-topic_ here, sorry. Refer to the Help Center what can be asked.

Comment: It's really easy: build the project and look at the output from the uic. Uic takes the XML `foo.ui` file and generates `ui_foo.h`. The latter is rather simple and boring C++ code that sets up the user interface. You can write such code yourself.

Comment: Congrats on your decision not to use Qt designer. You'll learn much faster without it. But using the generated code to learn from as Kuba Ober said is a good idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114389/qt-designer-vs-handcoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These references are useful if you have a background in C++ or a similar syntax language, like Java or Javascript.  Of course having the Qt Libraries and Qt Creator on your computer is an important pre-step, too.

Many different options have worked well for me:

1. Youtube - One pretty high quality one I found called VoidRealms did a good job of explaining what he was doing while he was doing it.  There may be other channels out there of similar quality, this is one that I've seen.  I don't remember if he spends a lot of time in Qt Designer or not, but he does show other methods, too.

   https://www.google.com/search?q=voidrealms+qt&safe=active&tbm=vid

   https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63
2. The Qt Conference Video Archive - At the Qt Conferences they record the slides and what was taught/discussed.  A number of these have great info on best practices with Qt.  Each video is about an hour long and goes pretty in depth.

   https://www.google.com/search?q=qt%20developer%20days%20videos
3. Welcome Tab > Examples - There are tons of well written and well documented examples.  I would pick one of those and make tweaks to it and see what happens... see what builds and what doesn't.

   http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html

   Here is a really comprehensive example.  There are many other quality ones, too.

   http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html
4. Read The Fine Manual.  Qt has set a high bar in excellence in its documentation.  When digging through someone else's code or the examples you click on any "Q" and press F1, and you get high quality information in plain english... or even any of the methods coming off of any of the instances of any of the functions.  I think the doxygen project was started trying to model its output after the Qt documentation.

   http://doc.qt.io/

   http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html

   The broad topics that come out are really good, too.

   http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/overviews-main.html#best-practices
5. Stackoverflow.  Sorting answers by votes yields a great source of FAQ's with quality answers.

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt?sort=votes&pageSize=50
6. Read a book;  the books for Qt development are well organized and written for learning it from scratch; most of the authors have many years of experience with it.

   https://wiki.qt.io/Books

   As you start down the path of Qt/C++, awareness of the QML/Qt Quick/Javascript side is important, too.  Qt Cascades Book has a lot of quality information.

   https://qmlbook.github.io/  (getting the zip of examples for each chapter out takes a few minutes to find)
7. Take a class, online or at a college.
8. Ask questions to a co-worker or professor or TA that has experience with it.

Hope that helps.